# How can I find a biking club that has a group for riding with kids in a trailer?

Tags: trailer, children, child-seat, group-rides

How can I find a biking club that has a group for riding with kids in a trailer? I prefer to ride in a group.

Comment: I've never heard of such a group, though there may be some in your larger urban areas.  Check your local bike shops, and try to find a local cycling club where maybe something can be organized.

Comment: Try meetup.com .

Comment: Where are you from? This might be important here.

Answer (score 3):

Besides talking to individuals in your local bike shops, you can look for 'recreational' or 'touring' clubs. A Google Search for [Bicycle Touring Clubs](http://www.google.com/search?q=bicycle%20touring%20clubs) turns up clubs like our club in Utah, [Bonneville Cycling Club](http://www.bbtc.net/) (formerly the Bonneville Bicycle Touring Club).

Larger recreational or touring clubs will usually rate their group rides by a couple of measures like distance and average speed, and will sometimes classify rides as drop/no drop (meaning that in a 'no drop', the group slows to the speed of the slowest rider).

Pick the slower and shorter rides to begin with, and be prepared to be fully self-supported.  I would welcome riders with a trailer or trail-a-bike on most of my recreational rides, but it can be frustrating if those riders really can't hang with the regulars.

Finally - try to preview the group's route if possible.  Most recreational group rides stick to quieter roads with wide shoulders, but you need to be aware that with the trailer you will be much harder to pass.

Answer (score 1):

Ask around your local bike shops for any groups or group rides. Then ride and get to know some of the other riders if they have kids and want to group ride with kids/trailers.

The biking community here is quite large and I don't know of anything like this, I suspect once you introduce yourself to a club or group, you may need to be the driving force and organize this sort of group ride.